# Unix - example of execute access without read access?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, permissions, directory

Can someone explain why you would  want to give one of your directories execute access but not read access?

Thanks!

Comment: So that you can open the directory and see the files but can't read them.

Comment: I was under the impression that read permission allows you to see the files. and execute allows you to cd the files.

Comment: with read permission linux allows to read all the content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from [why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened)

When applying permissions to directories on Linux, the permission bits have different meanings than on regular files.

> The write bit allows the affected user to create, rename, or delete
>   files within the directory, and modify the directory's attributes
>
> The read bit allows the affected user to list the files within the
>   directory
>
> The execute bit allows the affected user to enter the directory, and
>   access files and directories inside
>
> The sticky bit states that files and directories within that directory
>   may only be  deleted or renamed by their owner (or root)

So, if you give one of your directories execute access but not read access then affected user will be able to enter (`cd`) to the directory but will not be able to list the files within that directory.

Comment: I think the bottom two lines answer my question! I can't upvote yet but thank you.

Comment: @iamth3end, that's alright but try accepting it as answer by clicking the check mark button below the answer.

Comment: For a more realistic use case, note that `cd foo/bar` will fail if you don't have execute permission for `foo`, even if you *do* have execute permission for `foo/bar`.  To enter a directory, you need execute permission for every directory in the full path. Separating read access from entry allows you to hide the files in a directory without preventing access to subdirectories.